# Removing ::before and ::after pseudo-elements when class is-sticky is added

Tags: html, jquery, css, version-control

My problem is that when the class is-sticky is added to my menu, my ::before and ::after on logo are not necessary anymore. I'm not the biggest hero with Jquery and can't fix it with a online search.

the div

```
<div id='Top_bar' class='is-sticky'>
 <div class='container>
  <div class='top_bar_left>
   ::before
   <div class='logo>
   ::after

   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

My scss

```
.logo {
        background: #1A2741;
        padding: 0 50px;
        width: 13%;
        margin: 0 !important;

        #logo {
          margin-left: 39%;
        }

        &::before {
          content: ' ';
          background-image: url(../uploads/RH-Beelmerk.svg);
          height: 100px;
          width: 50px;
          position: absolute;
          padding: 50px;
          z-index: 2;
          top: -85%;
          left: 1%;
          transition: top 2s;
        }

        &:hover::before {
          top: -50%;
        }

        &::after {
          content: '';
          background: #1A2741;
          height: 110px;
          width: 50px;
          display: block;
          transform: rotate(10deg);
          position: absolute;
          left: 15.5%;
          top: -6%;
          z-index: 0;
          border-right: solid 4px #FF8496;
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either unset their content (`content: unset;`) or turn off their display (`display: none`).

For instance, here's unsetting the content *(which was originally posted as an answer by [doğukan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10698741/do%C4%9Fukan) but then deleted for some reason; since this answer was accepted, I've added that here and marked the post Community Wiki)*:

```
.is-sticky::before, .is-sticky::after {
    content: unset;
}
```

Depending on the selector adding them, you may need to make that more specific, but that's the general idea.

Example:

```js
setInterval(() => {
    document.querySelector(".target").classList.toggle("is-sticky");
}, 800);
```

```css
.target::before {
    content: 'before';
}
.target::after {
    content: 'after';
}
.is-sticky::before, .is-sticky::after {
    content: unset;
}
```

```html
<div class="target"> text </div>
```

Or turning the display of the content off instead:

```
.is-sticky::before, .is-sticky::after {
    display: none;
}
```

Example:

```js
setInterval(() => {
    document.querySelector(".target").classList.toggle("is-sticky");
}, 800);
```

```css
.target::before {
    content: 'before';
}
.target::after {
    content: 'after';
}
.is-sticky::before, .is-sticky::after {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="target"> text </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the condition with 'is-sticky' and unset the :before and :after children. Then you can just toggle the 'is-sticky' class on the logo. And keep in mind that :before and :after are children of your class-element, not elements outside of your class-element.

```
.logo{

   &.is-sticky{

    &:before, &:after{
       content: none;
    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using the CSS :not test, that way you don't get the pseudo elements if is-sticky is set.

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not#description):

> The :not() CSS pseudo-class represents elements that do not match a list of selectors. Since it prevents specific items from being selected, it is known as the negation pseudo-class.

e.g. `&:not('.is-sticky')::after` instead of &::after

That way you don't need any extra entries in the CSS.